# How can I bind parameters in a PHP PDO WHERE IN statement

Tags: php, pdo, where-in

Params:

```
$params = 2826558;                        # Necessary Object
$params = array(2826558,2677805,2636005); # NULL
```

Execution code:

```
    $data = $this->DQL_selectAllByCampaign_id()
                 ->execute( array($params) )
                 ->fetchAll();

    var_dump( $data );
```

SQL Query:

```
$this->DQL_selectAllByCampaign_id = $this->conn->prepare(

        "SELECT * FROM `banner` WHERE  `campaign_id` IN (?)"

);
```

If `$params` is Integer, returns necessary Object. 
If `$params` is Array, returns NULL.

After all, in fact it should work... How can I do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: Unfortunately I did not have access to PDO Object directly, I have only $this->DQL_selectAllByCampaign_id() wrapped method to `quote` current array value. I tried to implode(',',$params);, but unsuccesfully, receiving only row by id in first element of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure this isn't the 'right' answer, but we solved this by adding in count($array) placeholders. Then using call_user_func_array we pass the params in.

Thanks for asking this - will be interesing to find out what the proper way to do this is...

Comment: I found the solution of which you speak - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php. Apparently this is really the most common solution. But it is a crutch. I'll look for a solution more beautiful than this, and yet do so.